# flutter ci cd with github action and firebase app distribution

Tags: flutter, github-actions, firebase-app-distribution

im new with ci cd
so im trying to distribute my flutter project via github action
im following this youtube link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bMbJdZOWl2A
it kinda work, but the version of app in firebase is not like with the tag i pushed on my repo
and i ask chatGpt to fix this and also correct the release note from tag to match with release note in firebase, but it didn't work
this is my main.yml

```
name: Music Metric

on:
  push:
    tags:
      - '*'

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          distribution: "zulu"
          java-version: "11"
      - name: Decode google-services.json
        env: 
            GOOGLE_SERVICES_JSON: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_SERVICES_JSON }}
        run: echo "$GOOGLE_SERVICES_JSON" > android/app/google-services.json
      - name: Decode firebase_option
        env:
          firebase_options_dart: ${{secrets.FIREBASE_OPTION}}
        run : echo "$firebase_options_dart" > app/lib/firebase_options.dart

      - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
        with:
          channel: "stable"
      - run: dart pub global activate melos
      - run: melos bootstrap
      - run: melos gen-strings
      - run: flutter pub get
      - run: melos build-resources
      - run: cd app
      - run: cd lib
      - run: flutter pub get
      - run: flutter clean
      - run: flutter build apk app/lib/main.dart
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: release-apk
          path: build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk

      - name: Extract Version from Tag
        id: extract_version
        run: echo "::set-output name=version::$(echo ${{ github.ref }} | sed -n 's/refs\/tags\/v//p')"

      - name: Fetch Tag Message
        run: |
          git show --format="%m" ${{ steps.extract_version.outputs.tag }}
        id: get_tag_message

      - name: Upload Artifact to Firebase App Distribution
        uses: wzieba/Firebase-Distribution-Github-Action@v1
        with:
          appId: ${{ secrets.APPID }}
          token: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
          groups: pre-tester
          file: build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk
          releaseNotes: "Release for ${{ github.ref }}\n\n${{ steps.get_tag_message.outputs.tag-message }}"
          releaseNotesFile: ''
          appRelease: ${{ steps.extract_version.outputs.version }}
```

eg:
i push my new tag v1.0.7
with release note is "1"
[image: image tag]

and in firebase
it show this
[image]

i want in firebase it show like 1.0.7 and release note is 1
how can i resolve this

Comment: That is what you have configured in your workflow. Under `get_tag_message`, you're not setting the output correctly. `steps.extract_version.outputs.tag` should be `steps.extract_version.outputs.version`. Setting it properly should fix the message issue. See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter. In `releaseNotes`, you're using `github.ref` and that's what you're seeing. Use what you need it in there. Also, lint your workflow with https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/ to update it for deprecated features and typos.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your `${{ steps.extract_version.outputs.tag }}` by
`${{ steps.extract_version.outputs.version }}` and also,
replace your `${{ github.ref }}` by `${{ github.ref_name }}`

---

Comment: well it didnot work
it say 
Warning: Unexpected input(s) 'appRelease', valid inputs are ['entryPoint', 'args', 'appId', 'token', 'serviceCredentialsFile', 'serviceCredentialsFileContent', 'file', 'groups', 'testers', 'releaseNotes', 'releaseNotesFile', 'debug']